# sed replacing literal ${something} within xml tags

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying do the following:

```
find . -iname pom.xml 
| xargs sed -i 
 "s/<version>${project.version}</version>/<version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT</version>/g"
```

But it doesn't work. What all I need to escape here?

I tried multiple combinations like escaping `/` in version and `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape `$` and `.`. Use *different delimiter*(`;`).

```
sed "s;<version>\${project\.version}</version>;<version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT</version>;g"
```

Comment: +1 in particular for using a different delimiter (i generally use #, but it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 0):

The match string you want is `<version>\${project\.version}<\/version>` (escape the `$`, the `.`, and the `/`). The replace string you want is `<version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT<\/version>` (escape the `/`).

Combined that yields:

`"s/<version>\${project\.version}<\/version>/<version>0.9.1-SNAPSHOT<\/version>/g"`

Comment: Escaping the dots is correct, but whenever i find myself doing it, it strikes me as a bit pedantic; after all, an escaped dot will match a literal dot, and it's not like there's likely to be another string that matches `project.version`, is there?

Comment: @Tom Anderson You're right that in this particular example it's unlikely to make a difference, but it's a good habit to be in!